# Pixel range given by opencv on conversion to CIELUV and CIELAB is different from the standard

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, color-space

I am trying to use the CIELAB and CIELUV color space for doing some computer vision work. I used OpenCV to convert from RGB to the spaces

```py
img = cv2.imread(PATH)
img_Lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
img_Luv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LUV)
```

From what I have read, LUV has pixel values of L from 0 to 100 and U & V are -100 to 100. Same thing is given in this research paper I am referencing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13_Xd8RfDZyQRGuF2-_b6lFx0v2wMhu6d/view?usp=sharing

But OpenCV is giving pixel values as large as 236 and no negative values on converting to LUV. Similar is case for LAB. A and B ranges from -128 to 127, from what I have read, but OpenCV gives all +ve values. Why is that so? Is the range I am considering and mentioned in the paper wrong? If that is the case, what is the actual range?

Comment: why don't you have a look at the opencv documentation? https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_lab

Comment: @Miki I read it but didn't understood. what does 8bit, 16bit, 32bit images mean?

Comment: short answers: It is the `dtype` of your image.

Comment: @JoOkuma so is uint8 8bit image and uint32 32 bit? also, does the doc mean that if my image is 8bit, U V will have range 0 to 255?

Comment: @ShantanuShinde Yes. The values for uint8 are scaled to fit in an unsigned 8-bit integer.

Comment: can you put that as an answer so I can select it and close the question?